# Why does using a list as value in pandas row allow me to update on the fly?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, aggregate-functions, bioinformatics

I have some behaviour I don't understand. It would be great if someone could explain why this does work and also show me a nicer way to do this, it got very convoluted.

My goal here is to concatenate genetic variants that are next to each other on a given chromosome. This should find any variant combination up to 5 bp (position) long. What this means is that if there are 5 positions next to each other they should all be joined and then those positions should not be checked again. Then the same for combinations of length 4, 3, 2. I handle this with this line 'for var_len in [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]:' and the set already_updated. This solution works, but only if I put the 'tumour_alts' in a list in my df. Why is that? And can anyone show me how to get the same output without resorting to iteration?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['chr1',13,['A']],
              ['chr1',5,['A']],
              ['chr1',6,['G']],
              ['chr2',9,['G']],
               ['chr1',4,['C']],
              ['chr1',11,['T']]],
              columns=['chrom','pos','tumour_alts'],
             index=['chr1:13','chr1:5','chr1:6','chr2:9','chr1:4','chr1:11'])
already_updated = set([])
for chrom, df_tmp in df.groupby('chrom'):
    df_tmp = df_tmp.sort_values(by=['pos'])
    for var_len in [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]:
        df_tmp['dif'] = df_tmp.pos.diff(var_len)
        hits=df_tmp[df_tmp['dif'] == var_len]
        for hit in hits.pos:
            rows = df_tmp[(df_tmp.pos <= hit) & (df_tmp.pos >= (hit - var_len))]
            update = dict(rows.iloc[0])
            for i in range(var_len):
                i+=1
                update_tmp = dict(rows.iloc[i])
                key = update_tmp.get('chrom') + ':'+str(update_tmp.get('pos'))
                if key not in already_updated:
                    df = df.drop(index=(key))
                    update['tumour_alts'][0]+=update_tmp.get('tumour_alts')[0]
                    already_updated.add(key)


df

chrom   pos tumour_alts
chr1:13 chr1    13  [A]
chr2:9  chr2    9   [G]
chr1:4  chr1    4   [CAG]
chr1:11 chr1    11  [T]
```

Edit: I have increased the complexity to better describe the problem.

Given:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['chr1',13,['A']],
                   ['chr1',3,['A']],
                  ['chr1',5,['A']],
                  ['chr1',6,['G']],
                  ['chr2',9,['G']],
                   ['chr1',4,['C']],
                  ['chr1',11,['T']],
                  ['chr1',55,['A']],
                  ['chr1',56,['G']],
                  ['chr2',95,['G']],],
                  columns=['chrom','pos','tumour_alts'],
                 index=['chr1:13','chr1:3','chr1:5','chr1:6','chr2:9','chr1:4','chr1:11','chr1:55','chr1:56','chr1:95'])
df = df.sort_values('pos').sort_values('chrom')
```

I expect:

```
chrom   pos tumour_alts
chr1:3  chr1    3   [ACAG]
chr1:11 chr1    11  [T]
chr1:13 chr1    13  [A]
chr1:55 chr1    55  [AG]
chr2:9  chr2    9   [G]
chr2:95 chr2    95  [G]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using groupby rather than the for-loop. Also, I am unsure what you mean by "This should find any variant combination up to 5 bp (position) long" so I did not include this into the code below.

```
# remove characters from list
df['tumour_alts'] = df['tumour_alts'].astype(str).str.replace("\[|\]", '').str.replace("'", '')
# sort values
df = df.sort_values('pos')
# groupby chrom (assuming you need to group these together)
g = df.groupby('chrom')['pos']
# check the value above and below to see if they are == eachother
mask = ~((g.shift(0) == g.shift(-1)-1) | (g.shift(0) == g.shift(1)+1))
# use cumsum to assign a number value for each group
gr = mask.cumsum()-mask.cumsum().where(~mask).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
# groupby gr and transform with sum to append strings together
s = df.groupby(gr)['tumour_alts'].transform(sum).drop_duplicates(keep='first').to_frame()
# drop column and merge right
df.drop(columns='tumour_alts').merge(s, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='right')

        chrom  pos tumour_alts
chr1:4   chr1    4         CAG
chr2:9   chr2    9           G
chr1:11  chr1   11           T
chr1:13  chr1   13           A
```

although the above code does produce your expected output I do not know much about chromosomes so `drop_duplicates` may not be appropriate. You may want to merge everything together and then drop the rows based on the appropriate params.

```
# remove characters from list
df['tumour_alts'] = df['tumour_alts'].astype(str).str.replace("\[|\]", '').str.replace("'", '')
# sort values
df = df.sort_values('pos')
# groupby chrom (assuming you need to group these together)
g = df.groupby('chrom')['pos']
# check the value above and below to see if the are == eachother
mask = ~((g.shift(0) == g.shift(-1)-1) | (g.shift(0) == g.shift(1)+1))
# use cumsum to assign a number value for each group
gr = mask.cumsum()-mask.cumsum().where(~mask).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
# groupby gr and transform with sum to append strings together
s = df.groupby(gr)['tumour_alts'].transform(sum).to_frame()
# merge right
df.merge(s, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='right')

        chrom  pos tumour_alts_x tumour_alts_y
chr1:4   chr1    4             C           CAG
chr1:5   chr1    5             A           CAG
chr1:6   chr1    6             G           CAG
chr2:9   chr2    9             G             G
chr1:11  chr1   11             T             T
chr1:13  chr1   13             A             A
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited my question to explain further what I meant re 'This should find any variant combination up to 5 bp (position) long'. What this means is that if there are 5 positions next to each other they should all be joined and then those positions should not be checked again. Then the same for 4, 3, 2. I handle this with this line 'for var_len in [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]:' and the set already_updated.

Comment: This is a very nice solution. I have learnt a lot from it. I have tried to modify it to work for the increased complexity now described in the question. The mask can be expanded to capture multiple lines as such 'mask = ~((g.shift(0) == g.shift(-1)-1) | (g.shift(0) == g.shift(1)+1) | (g.shift(0) == g.shift(-2)-2) | (g.shift(0) == g.shift(2)+2))
'. However, the 'gr' line needs to create something unique for each combination of variants which are to be collapsed AND for each variant that is not to be collapsed. Is that possible?